# how to float a vertical menu to the right of the website, and open sub-menu's to the left (instead of right)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I'm building a responsive menu.  The bigger versions of this menu work great.  Here is what the menu looks like expanded:

[image: fully expanded menu]

When the page gets smaller, the menu disappears (using `display: hidden;` in CSS).  A "Menu" link appears in this version in place of the horizontal menu.  I just hide the menu button in the larger versions of the responsive site.

[image]

The menu button is `position: fixed; right: 0;` to fix it right within a container.  I'm using 100% widths for a lot of things on this size of site, so `position: absolute; right: 0;` wouldn't even work because it doesn't know exactly how wide screen is.

**What my problem is:** I'm using jquery to toggle the vertical menu that opens below the "menu" link.  It is opening off the page.  Also, I'm not familiar with setting up vertical sub-menu's opening to the left and was hoping someone could help with that.  All of my sub-menu's open to the right (which would put it off the page again).

**What I need:** I need to figure out how to fix this code to have the "parent" level of this vertical menu to float to the right of the page and open right under the "menu" links (either with css or jquery), and then get the child elements to open to the left and not the right.  The menu does not need to float up and down the page (the vertical menu ONLY appears if "menu" is hovered over"....so the vertical menu needs to stay open if the menu is hovered over as well.

Thanks in advance.  I'm not use to working with this style menu.

**Code:**

HTML:

```
<a id="menu_button" class="hidecontent_full hidecontent_condensed" href="#">Menu</a>

<div class="nav fixedright">
<ul>
<li class="first"><a href="#">New?</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Welcome</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">What We Believe</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">When and Where</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Crossroads Staff</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Next Steps</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">What is Next Steps?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Connect</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Grow</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Serve</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Ministries</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Childrens Ministry</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Student Ministry</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Connect Groups</a>
    <li><a href="#">Music Ministry</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Prayer Groups</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Resources</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sermon Archives</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Church Community Builder</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Parents</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bible Reading Plans</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Recommended Books</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="last"><a href="#">Events</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Fall Festival Campout</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Let's Paint</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dinner for 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Calendar of Events</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Give</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">How to Give</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Give Online</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

</ul>
</div>  <!-- navigation -->
```

CSS: (for one that I want the menu to float to the right on)

```
#header_whitebox #menu_button { position: fixed; right: 0; padding: 20px 15px 25px 15px; }
/* NAVIGATION */
#header_whitebox .nav { display: none; position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0; height: 75px; }
#header_whitebox .nav ul { font-size: 1em; line-height: 1.2em; list-style: none; display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 100; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#header_whitebox .nav ul li { float: none; font-size: 13px; margin-left: -1px;  min-width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; border-left: 1px solid #ccc; border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }
#header_whitebox .nav ul li a { display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #282828; padding: 10px 11px; white-space: nowrap; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; letter-spacing: 1px;  min-width: 200px; background: #fff;  }
#header_whitebox .nav ul li:hover a { color: #2C59A7; }

/* SUB NAVIGATION */
#header_whitebox .nav li ul { display: none; position: relative; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; }
#header_whitebox .nav li:hover ul { display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 100; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#header_whitebox .nav li:hover li { float: none; font-size: 13px; margin-left: -1px;  min-width: 75px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; border-left: 1px solid #ccc; border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }
#header_whitebox .nav li:hover li a { display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #282828; padding: 10px 11px; white-space: nowrap; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; letter-spacing: 1px;  min-width: 200px; background: #fff; }
#header_whitebox .nav li:hover li:hover a {  color: #2C59A7; }
```

jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu_button").hover(function(){
    $('.nav').slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
```